# Modify CSS Hover Hyperlink Effect

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I need to modify the css hover effect on my link. This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <div class="center-content">
            <a href="#" class="btn1">
                <span> Some Link </span>
                <span> </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So, the css effect works with background of the link. How can I modify my css to apply the same effect of 'filling with color' to the text color instead of background?
http://jsfiddle.net/yakovenkodenis/ryfyhLk7/ Here is the needed effect, but it changes background, not text itself.
Here is my css code:

```
body {
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    color: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    margin: 100px 0;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button-holder > div > div, .button-holder > div > a {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 80px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.center-content {
  width: 840px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.button-holder div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.btn1 span {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.95);
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 9px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #444;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.btn1 { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn1 span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 9px 0;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.95);
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #444;
}
.btn1 span:first-of-type {
  z-index: 99999;
}
.btn1 span:last-of-type {
  background: #1abc9c;
  left: -100%;
}
.btn1:hover span {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about so vague explanation and so much code. Hope you still can help

Comment: why did you decide to have a second span you move across on hover? can you not just have one and change it's background and text color on hover? `.btn1:hover span { background: #1abc9c; color:red; }`

Comment: Well, if I remove the second span it stops working:)
(The code isn't really mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is by far not a perfect solution, but it demonstrates the principle behind what I'm doing.

This is tough because CSS doesn't give us control over individual characters. The easiest way to do this is to make the text itself transparent and then use a CSS3 animation to change the `background-color`. Webkit browsers have a way to do that in code alone, but for a fallback, you'll need to use either JavaScript or graphics with transparent text.

The code:

```
<div id="outer">
  <p>Some link</p>
</div>

#outer {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #1abc9c 50%, #444 50%);
  background-size:200% 100%;
  background-position:right bottom;
  font-size:64px;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
#outer:hover {
  background-position:left  bottom;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

I'm taking advantage of `-webkit-background-clip` and `-webkit-text-fill-color` as explained in this [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) article. Webkit takes advantage of the CSS3 property which cuts out the text and allows color or images from behind to be shown. **As far as I can tell, this only works in Webkit browsers**.

Then, I used the `linear-gradient` property for the background. 50% of it is in the default color, the other 50% is your hover color. When you hover the div, the background shifts, giving the appearance of text filling with a different color.

## [Here's the CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/emBzYp)

Again, I only tested this with WebKit. If you use images with transparent text, you can achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're css god! :) At least it works in chrome!

Comment: The article I linked has some fallback options which might be helpful. Make sure to read that through as well. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't examine what all you are trying to do, but this change works:

and here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nq0s16q3/

```
.btn1:hover span {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have asked if I needed only a simple color transition:) There's a special hover effect for the background of the link. I need to make the same effect, but for the text color itself, not its background.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yakovenkodenis/ryfyhLk7/
Here it is. But it changes background. I need to change text-color the same way instead of background

Comment: This changes the text color on hover, just like you had asked.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing the effect you speak of. I see a color change on hover, but no flashy transition. I'm actually trying to figure out now whether there is some overriding CSS at work here.

Comment: AH...he's using CSS3 transformations, but only has the `moz` prefix in his code, so it isn't animating on Chrome.

Comment: I'm being too unclear, sorry guys. So, here is the source: http://jsfiddle.net/yakovenkodenis/ryfyhLk7/
When you hover the link, you can see that background start fiiling with grenn color from leftto right. I want the same behaviour with the text-color

Comment: No. As Mr. Bennett has explained, anyone attempting to fix your problem needs to not be using Chrome browser. I'll check it out in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In your css you have

```
.btn1 span:last of type {
  background: #1abc9c;
  left: 100%;
}
```

you can try changing it to

```
.btn1:hover span {
  color: #1abc9c;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This didn't really help. Probably, I'm being to0 unclear, sorry about that. So, there's a background hover effect (green color start going from left to right when hovered). I need to make the same effect with the text instead of background. I want it to fill with green color from left to right (just what's happening with background when you hover the link).
http://jsfiddle.net/yakovenkodenis/ryfyhLk7/

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of your **a** elements text on *hover* just add a `color` property to your `.btn1:hover span` selector:

`.btn1:hover span {
  left: 0;
  color: red;
}`